# How many waves from a boat wake

Tags: waves

How many visible waves does a boat wake create?
How do boat size, speed, and other factors determine how many waves there will be?

Define "visible wave" as a wave with amplitude greater than or equal to some threshold $A$ which is up to your interpretation.
A reasonable value might be $A = 1 \, \text{cm}$.

Comment: By the "number" you mean a number of visible wave peaks?

Comment: @VictorPira Yeah, that's really the only sensible way to read this. Certainly the question boils down to 1) How much amplitude does the boat make in the wake waves?, and 2) What is the attenuation of waves in water? Interesting question, actually.

Answer (score 2):

as usual for this kind of question: an infinite number, but their fading intensity will make them un-noticable after a while. see http://www.wikiwaves.org/Ship_Kelvin_Wake and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake .

As illustrated in these [images](https://www.google.fr/search?q=kelvin%20wake&safe=off&sa=X&espv=2&biw=1205&bih=890&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0CCMQsARqFQoTCLS2l4Hp8cgCFUx_GgodaFwGhg), the pattern of emission is a repeated curvy triangle, which front corresponds to long wavelengths on the rear and shorter and shorter wavelengths for larger angles. Then one or the other part can be faded depending on the size and speed of the boat (which favor some sizes of wavelengths), so that you might see only the horizontal waves on the rear (for large slow boat) or only the "V" waves on the sides (for a fast small boat).

This is for the Kelvin wake. Now in addition you have a few other kind of wakes and waves around: Karman street vortices, turbulent wake caused by a powerful propeller, front shock wave, collapsing waves, secondary waves, capillary waves on top of all that... But the typical "ship waves" are the Kelvin wake.